# SQLite - getting number of rows in a database

Tags: sqlite

I want to get a number of rows in my table using `max(id)`. When it returns `NULL` - if there are no rows in the table - I want to return 0. And when there are rows I want to return `max(id) + 1`.

My rows are being numbered from 0 and autoincreased.

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(id) != NULL THEN (MAX(id) + 1) ELSE 0 END FROM words
```

But it is always returning me 0. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use the MAX(id) instead of the count, after reading the comments from Pax then the following SQL will give you what you want

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id)+1, 0) FROM words
```

Comment: Clever but only works if you have an auto int pk with base 0. VolkerK's answer is simpler and more effective.

Comment: @Rich. VolkerK's answer is indeed simpler and is the solution I would have gone with myself, however, the question stated that the OP wanted to use max(id) and that rows were numbered from 0 and auto-increased.

Comment: @JoeLyga, that's very odd. The COALESCE function was added to Sqlite version 2.4.0 in March 2002. Do you have a really ancient version?

Answer (score 257):

You can query the actual number of rows with

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM tblName
```

see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Comment: This will indeed always work, but it requires sqlite to enumerate all the rows in the table.  It's inefficient if the number of rows is large (> 10,000, say)

Comment: Thus use `select count(rowid) from tblName;` for faster access and `==`  number of rows in table more efficiently than using a field declared in the `create table` schema.

Comment: Any way to get this without counting? Like from some metadata SQLite maintains? I'm looking at a 300GB SQLite db file I need to get info from... A COUNT takes up to 30m to run.

Answer (score 9):

In SQL, NULL = NULL is false, you usually have to use IS NULL:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(id) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE (MAX(id) + 1) END FROM words
```

But, if you want the number of rows, you should just use `count(id)` since your solution will give 10 if your rows are (0,1,3,5,9) where it should give 5.

If you can guarantee you will always ids from 0 to N, max(id)+1 *may* be faster depending on the index implementation (it may be faster to traverse the right side of a balanced tree rather than traversing the whole tree, counting.

But that's very implementation-specific and I would advise against relying on it, not least because it locks your performance to a specific DBMS.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if I understand your question, but max(id) won't give you the number of lines at all. For example if you have only one line with id = 13 (let's say you deleted the previous lines), you'll have max(id) = 13 but the number of rows is 1. The correct (and fastest) solution is to use count(). BTW if you wonder why there's a star, it's because you can count lines based on a criteria.

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem if i understand your question correctly, I want to know the last inserted id after every insert performance in SQLite operation. i tried the following statement:

```
select * from table_name order by id desc limit 1
```

The id is the first column and primary key of the table_name, the mentioned statement show me the record with the largest id.

But the premise is u never deleted any row so the numbers of id equal to the numbers of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Extension of VolkerK's answer, to make code a little more readable, you can use AS to reference the count, example below:

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS c from profile`

This makes for much easier reading in some frameworks, for example, i'm using Exponent's (React Native) Sqlite integration, and without the AS statement, the code is pretty ugly.