# SQLite - Insert Into myTable Select Count (*) From myTable Where Date = 'mydate' Syntax Error

Tags: sqlite

I'm attempting to count the number of rows of a table where the date = a date in another table. The result of this query I want inserted into the row of another table where the date is equivalent to the date used to count the relevant rows to be counted.

I found this thread which is helpful:
The [Select Count(*) function works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669092/sqlite-getting-number-of-rows-in-a-database)

However when I go to Insert the Count to the table-labeled column, there is no insertion taking place nor an error.

My actual code:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."LookUpWrkflwTemp" (SpiralUniverse)
   SELECT Count (*)
   FROM SpiralUniverse 
   WHERE Date = '2015-11-16';
```

There is a table named SpiralUniverse and a column within LookUpWrkflwTemp named SpiralUniverse.

My ultimate goal is to add a date to LookUpWrkflwTemp(Date) then perform record counts that match that date in a variety of tables and insert those values into the appropriate columns named after those tables. The above code snippet is for one column insertion and the date is hard coded.

ex. LookUpWrkflwTemp(Date,ImportDailyList,SpiralUniverse,...) is my table and columns that I want to insert record count values within the matching Date row. ImportDailyList and SpiralUniverse are the different tables where I want to search for date matching record counts.

What am I missing in the syntax in the above code snippet?

edit:

```
Sample data for LookUpWrkflwTemp(Date,ImportDailyList,SpiralUniverse,...)
rowid   Date        ImportDailyList   SpiralUniverse
1     2015-11-15        null               1
2     2015-11-16        null               4    <---record count and insert                           into this table that I´m looking for



Sample data for SpiralUniverse
rowid   Date         Symbol
1     2015-11-16     ACOR
2     2015-11-16     COR
3     2015-11-16     AAPL
4     2015-11-16     TSLA
5     2015-11-15     TSLA
...
```

sqlite does not generate a syntax error nor correctly inserts the record count even though the Select Count(*) function works correctly. I suspect the problem is with the INSERT INTO or in the WHERE clause.

Comment: so, you want to insert a row into a temp table, where the count column comes form an another table, right? thats all?

Comment: No. The table is a persistent table, the count column comes from another table where the date matches the date in the persistent table.

Comment: Can you add sample data for `LookUpWrkflwTemp` and `SpiralUniverse` and any other table involved, and also include result you wish to obtain?

Comment: also, could you insert here the exact sql error? because in this case this code needs to work, I changed the table and rows name to my ones, and it worked...

Comment: @zedfoxus, thank you for clarifying my question.

Comment: @golddragon007, sqlite does not produce an error. I´m of the same mindset that this sql statement should work, however it does not.

Comment: it's always produces, not as specified like mysql or other, but always is, if there's an error in your code, i.e. you can get constraint error, syntax error, ect, you need only to try{}catch(){} it

Comment: also I used sqlite in firefox extension, in c# form app, and now I using it in windows store app, I always get exeption if there was an error in the SQL code... you just need to catch it and write it out. More info in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert a new record to that table:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."LookUpWrkflwTemp" (Date, SpiralUniverse) VALUES('2015-11-16', (
   SELECT Count (*)
   FROM SpiralUniverse 
   WHERE Date = '2015-11-16');
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO "main"."LookUpWrkflwTemp" (Date, SpiralUniverse)
   SELECT '2015-11-16', Count (*)
   FROM SpiralUniverse 
   WHERE Date = '2015-11-16';
```

In that case ONLY if your rowid is autoincrement and the other columns has default value or can be NULL.

If you have that date into the LookUpWrkflwTemp table, you can also insert a new row, but in that case, you will have two row, which has the same date. You can also `UPDATE` your row.

```
UPDATE "LookUpWrkflwTemp" SET SpiralUniverse = (
  SELECT Count (*)
  FROM SpiralUniverse 
  WHERE Date = '2015-11-16') WHERE Date = '2015-11-16'; -- or by rowid = x where x is the correct rows rowid
```

Also you can get multiple count at insert from different tables:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."LookUpWrkflwTemp" (Date, ImportDailyList, SpiralUniverse) VALUES('2015-11-16', (
   SELECT Count (*)
   FROM ImportDailyList 
   WHERE Date = '2015-11-16'), (
   SELECT Count (*)
   FROM SpiralUniverse 
   WHERE Date = '2015-11-16');
```

The `"main".` isn't necessary, only if you want to refer to another database.

For example with my db:
tags(id, name, date)
files(id, favorite, added, ...)
Both cases the ID is PrimaryKey and is autoincrement.

files data:

```
id  favorite    date
1       0       2015-11-30 23:25:44
2       1       2015-11-30 23:25:44
3       1       2015-11-30 23:25:44
4       0       2015-11-30 23:25:44
5       0       2015-11-30 23:40:17
```

tags table empty

In this case:

```
Query executed successfully:
INSERT INTO "tags" (name) 
  SELECT count (*) FROM files
  WHERE added = '2015-11-30 23:25:44' (took 0ms)

Tags table:
id  name    date
1   4       NULL

Query executed successfully: 
INSERT INTO "tags" (name, date) 
  SELECT count (*), '2015-11-30 23:25:44' FROM files
  WHERE added = '2015-11-30 23:25:44' (took 0ms)

Tags table:
id  name    date
1   4       NULL
2   4       2015-11-30 23:25:44

Query executed successfully: 
INSERT INTO "tags" (name, date) 
  SELECT count (*), '2015-11-30 23:25:44' FROM files
  GROUP BY favorite (took 0ms)


Tags table:
id  name    date
1   4       NULL
2   4       2015-11-30 23:25:44
3   3       2015-11-30 23:25:44
4   2       2015-11-30 23:25:44

Query executed successfully: 
INSERT INTO "tags" (name, date) 
  SELECT count (*), added FROM files GROUP BY favorite, added (took 0ms)

Tags table:
id  name    date
1   4       NULL
2   4       2015-11-30 23:25:44
3   3       2015-11-30 23:25:44
4   2       2015-11-30 23:25:44
5   2       2015-11-30 23:25:44
6   1       2015-11-30 23:40:17
7   2       2015-11-30 23:25:44
```

and finally one update:

```
Query executed successfully: 
UPDATE tags SET name = (
  SELECT count (*) FROM files WHERE added = '2015-11-30 23:25:44') 
WHERE date = '2015-11-30 23:25:44' (took 0ms)

Tags table:
id  name    date
1   4       NULL
2   4       2015-11-30 23:25:44
3   4       2015-11-30 23:25:44
4   4       2015-11-30 23:25:44
5   4       2015-11-30 23:25:44
6   1       2015-11-30 23:40:17
7   4       2015-11-30 23:25:44
```

Now I emptied the tags table and I removed from the id column the primarykey and autoincrement values, also this column has NOT NULL property:
Then I try to run this:

```
INSERT INTO "tags" (name) 
  SELECT count (*) FROM files
  WHERE added = '2015-11-30 23:25:44'
```

And I get this:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: tags.id: INSERT INTO "tags" (name) 
  SELECT count (*) FROM files
  WHERE added = '2015-11-30 23:25:44'
```

Also try out SqliteBrowser (http://sqlitebrowser.org/) it's usefull, you can open sqlite DB and you can run code. I tried those code's with this app, also it shows the sqlite exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth reply. The final piece is around  passing the date value in the query instead of having the date hard coded.

"If you have that date into the LookUpWrkflwTemp table, you can also insert a new row, but in that case, you will have two row, which has the same date. You can also UPDATE your row."

Thank you for the foresight. In this example of yours, what would the syntax be in the WHERE clause if I wanted to search for a date to pass into this query stored as a value in LookUpWrkflwTemp ? In other words the row which only contains a new date, all other values are null.

Comment: I am using SqliteBrowser for Firefox. It does not give an error like I´m used to seeing. I trust that what you say is correct, however in my case there is no error nor insertion (with my code).

Comment: In my example the count column is the name in the tags, so I need to do this: WHERE name IS NULL also, if you interested in multiple columns: WHERE column1 IS NULL AND column2 IS NULL .... This will result those rows, which doen't have count() value in my case in the tags table

Comment: oh, I used SQLite Manager for firefox, it's an extension. pritty slow, but it works great, and shows the error if you run the code there

Comment: I notice that in your examples you´ve explicitly defined the time in the date field. In my example, I´ve only specified a date with no time, could that be an issue in terms of matching the correct records?

Comment: nop, in my case the date field is a VARCHAR field, it can be anything in it. 
Open your table and see where is unique property, which column can be null or not. If there's an unique column, you need to fill it with unique value (unique in that table in that column), and if there's a not null column, you need to fill it. Also, how you try to execute?

Comment: did you get it? maybe I missunderstood your question about "I´ve only specified a date with no time", you need to specify the time too, if you have "datetime fields" or you can use LIKE "2015-02-01%"

Comment: Ok, the above works. Thank you! I´ve created a follow-up question based on your above answers.